# get the value of ngModel typed element in a loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table of products for which I want to calculate a discount.

I don't have the discount type in my class for the product which made it difficult because whenever I calculate the discounts it gets applicated to all the elements of the loop.

My question is: is there any way to get the value of the only input typed and not loop over all of the elements?

I did the following:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>product</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>discount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let prod of products">
      <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
      <td>{{prod.price}}Dhs</td>
      <td>
        <input 
          type="number"
          (keyup.enter)="calculateDiscount(prod.price)"
          [(ngModel)]="discount"
          placeholder="0"
        >
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is how I calculate the discount

```js
calculateDiscount(price?: number): void {
  this.pricepr = price;
  if (this.pricepr !== undefined) {
    this.discounttotal=((this.pricepr*(this.discount))/100);
    console.log(this.discounttotal)

    this.totalwithDiscount=this.total-this.discounttotal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is the **NgModel**.
You are using a single variable, **discount**, across all the elements of your ***ngFor**.

The following would be my code implementation:

```js
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  discounts: number[];
  discountsPerc: number[];
  // Other variables here

  ngOnInit() {
    // Other code here
    this.discounts = Array(this.products.length).fill(0) // This is ES6 syntax, but other ways exist
    this.discountsPerc = Array(this.products.length).fill(0)
  }

  calculateDiscount(index: number, discount: number): void {
    if (this.products[index].price === undefined) return;
      // Discount percentage must be between 0 and 100;
      this.discountsPerc[index]=  Math.max((Math.min(discount, 0), 100)/100);
      // Based on the value, we calculate the discounted price of each product;
      this.discount[index] = this.products[index].price * this.discountsPerc[index];
      this.calculateTotal();
    }
  }

  calculateTotal(): void {
    this.total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      // If the discount value is 0 then not discount is applyed and the original price is added.
      this.total += this.discounts[i] || this.products[i].price;
    }
  }
}
```

And the HTML would be:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>product</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>discount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let prod of products; let i = index">
      <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
      <td>{{prod.price}}Dhs</td>
      <td>
        <input 
          type="number"
          (keyup.enter)="calculateDiscount(i)"
          [(ngModel)]="discounts[i]"
          placeholder="0"
        >
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now what is happening?

1. I'm creating two variables, **discounts** and **discountsPerc**. The first holds the value of the discounted item, the second holds the discount percentage.
2. In the **ngOnInit** and initializing the variables which are an array with the same length of the products I have, so I always have a one-to-one match between my produts and their discounts.
3. When the user inputs a value in the discount, I verify if there is a price. If so I calculate the discount rate (added some security for better results) and update the discount value of the item and the discount percentage.
4. I calculate in a separate method the total by summing the discounts when these exist (value of the discount is non-zero), and when they don't exist, I sum the original price using the **|| (OR)** operator.
5. I update the **NgModel** to use the discounts array and the calculateDiscount by passing the index of the element that is being modifyed.